# VB.NET forms behave strange on design-time

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm developing with VB.NET 2008.
One of my host was crashed, so I take the files and keep development on another host. But now something strange is happening:All frames, lines and shapes are disappeared on design-time, but are seen normally in runtime.
Please see the attached screenshot (Upper is design-time, lower is runtime).
http://gomidjets.com/forms.JPG

How do I fix this?

#### Update:

The shapes are `GroupBox` and `LineShape`. `LineShape` is part of "VisualBasic PowerPack" indeed.

If I try to add a line shape, it is added but invisible in the designer, while it's visible during the run-time.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just lost track of the Zorder in the designer?

Answer (score 0):

If i was you i'd most definitely check the zorder.
As a last resort take the controls out of the groupbox and recreate the groupbox.
Also if you add a groupbox or a lineshape control on another form,does it work? if they do,you should check your code